# How to position an inner - inner tag at different position?

Tags: html, css, menu

I asked a more basic question before ([How can I position an inner tag at different position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458787/how-can-i-position-an-inner-tag-at-different-position)) and it was answered perfectly.
But I forgot about the deeper sub-levels..
The basic problem is that the top-level items are displayed in a different position on the page than the sub-level ones..

So the structure looks now like this:

```
<div id="menu">
    <div class="body-menu">
        <ul>
            <li class="current"><div class="body-menu">
                <a href="bla">Item1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="current"><div class="body-menu">
                        <a href="bla">Item 1.1</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li class=""><div class="body-menu">
                                <a href="bla">Item 1.1.1</a>
                            </div></li>
                            <li class="current deepest-menu"><div class="body-menu">
                                <a href="bla">Item 1.1.2</a>
                            </div></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div></li>
                    <li class=""><div class="body-menu">
                        <a href="bla">Item 1.2</a>
                    </div></li>
                </ul>
            </div></li>
            <li class=""><div class="body-menu">
                <a href="bla">Item 2</a>
            </div></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-background"></div>
</div>
```

I used this code to fix the basic problem of showing the sub-level ones in the left-side-menu and the top-level at their original position (top menu)

```
.body-menu > ul > li {
 position:relative;
 padding-bottom: 1em;
}
.body-menu ul ul {
 position:absolute;
 left:10px;
 top:30px;
}
```

but now the items at level 1.1.1 are displaying over the 1.1 ones...

is there an easy solution to this?

thanks in every case for your help!
--crisler

---

## UPDATE

css stuff
http://jsfiddle.net/crisler/wZrVS/ (simple)
http://jsfiddle.net/crisler/pMTHX/1/ (more items..)
a little bit crowded because most of it is from the university css file..
hope i got everything

Comment: Could you possibly provide all CSS associated with this HTML so we can drop it into JS fiddle and tinker around with it?

Comment: sure, hope I got everyting: http://pastebin.com/zH8cdWMn

Comment: I seem to be having trouble getting that link to load... Could you paste it into jsFiddle or stackoverflow? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/crisler/wZrVS/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this CSS instead:

```
.body-menu ul ul.second-level {
    position:absolute;
    left:10px;
    top:30px;
}
```

And add a `second-level` class to all the `ul`s that are immediately nested after the first level items (ie. *Item 1*, *Item 2*, ...):

```
<a href="bla">Item1</a>
    <ul class="second-class">
```

The problem  is that you are applying that CSS rule to *all* the sublists in your code. With this change it will only affect to the second level of lists, and the rest will behave normally.

This is the result:

[image: nested lists]

And this is the edited fiddle (the one with more items): http://jsfiddle.net/pMTHX/2/